# Heuristics on when should one subclass and when not

Tags: design, object-oriented, inheritance, class-design

Are there any good tips, when one should subclass and when should not?

It's clear that we should **not** subclass when

- we want to reuse a single method of some class
- we override all methods, changing the behavior of superclass completely.

But in real life, it's more difficult to decide. For example, I have a `BasicToolbar` class, which has several buttons arranged on a panel. There is a second class `ExtendedToolbar`, which hould

- have some additional buttons
- change the ordering of all buttons
- on condition hide/remove a couple of buttons from parent class

I tend to subclass to reuse those buttons and override ordering/addition logic, but occasional removing of a button of the parent class seem to be against idea of inheritance.

Any opinion is welcome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1338391

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14165147

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076814/core-java/inheritance-versus-composition--which-one-should-you-choose-.html ... and many others.

Comment: thanks you for the links, I think composition will not work in my case, so it's either inheritance or another sibling class

Comment: I think you summed it up quite nicely in your case. "Removing a button" is not so much against the idea of inheritance if you put a "ButtonXXVisible" property in the base class, and set it in the derived class. Then it becomes simply an initial property value.

Comment: Composition always works. The difference between inheritance and composition is that inheritance automatically forwards all method (whether you want them or not) and composition requires that you create a wrapper for each method you want forwarded.

Comment: While some of the tips are probably "dated" or even "wrong" as it was written when OO was just starting to take hold in the industry, the book "OO Design Heuristics" by Arthur Riel still contains many tips worth learning. Some are obvious, others require a little thought to grasp. This web site lists the heuristics but the book explains the reasoning and gives examples. http://www.vincehuston.org/ood/oo_design_heuristics.html In particular, there are 18 heuristics regarding the inheritance relationship, of which a few might be considered "wrong" today, but they should be helpful none-the-less.

Comment: If you are just concerned with your specific example then it seems pretty clear that your BasicToolbar class should just be a container and you add/remove buttons to it any ordering you like. There is no need for an ExtendedToolbar class. I think your ExtendedToolbar violates heuristic 52 "Do not confuse optional containment with the need for inheritance." from the aforementioned book.

Answer (score 4):

The **Liskov Substiution Principle** is by far the best "heuristic" I know of for determining whether direct subclassing is a good idea.

Say you have a base class Foo, and derived classes Bar1 through Bar9. In a nutshell, the LSP states that *any block of code using a Foo must work correctly no matter which of the nine Bar types that Foo actually is*.

From the user's point of view, that means code using the base class should be able to work almost exclusively with that base class, without caring what the actual type of the object is.

From the implementer's point of view, that means each subclass must implement the full interface of the base class, including all of the implied semantic properties, without any surprises or additional restrictions.

If the subclass you're thinking of writing won't follow these rules, that's a very strong indication you should not be using inheritance.

---

Regarding your toolbar example, I don't think it makes a lot of sense to use inheritance that way. I'd rather have Button classes, a generic Toolbar class that can contain any arrangement of Buttons, and then make BasicToolbar and ExtendedToolbar be objects with a Toolbar member that they add Buttons to in their constructors. If they share a bunch of buttons, make BackButton/LikeButton/UpvoteButton classes with a Button member, and let the Toolbars contain them. Using inheritance anywhere in this arrangement will only add unnecessarily tight restrictions on how you can rearrange these classes in the future.

Comment: I agree with your logic. However, practically speaking, in most programming enviornments, putting superfluous UI elements in a base class, and showing them programmatically, usually is easier than creating separate UI component classes. Perhaps it should not be an inheritance issue at all, but rather deciding which properties should be in the class.

Comment: Well, if there is code in your two Toolbars that could be shared, that's code which can go in a "generic" container class. If there really isn't any code to share, then just have two unrelated classes. "It should not be an inheritance issue" is definitely what I'm trying to get at.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the conventions and guidelines for a specific programming language. In C# it is not easy to delegate methods to an inner object (it requires explicit code). So inheritance can be easier. When creating a public .net based API, inheritance is often recommended, to simplify discovery for the API user.

Answer (score 0):

One common use is when you want to use the [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

I that pattern you write the skeleton of an algorithm in an abstrac class. In some parts of that skeleton you can certain methods that are not implemented.

Subclassed implement those methods completing the algorithm. That can also be achieved without inheritance using injection and or delegates.

In general you should not subclass where there is not "is a" relationship between class.

Another patter that uses inheritance is the decorator patter which is similar to the toolbar example you gave.